# Select ListBox items using comma separated values in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, listbox

I am saving the selected ListBox items values in a comma separated string.

```
private string fabricString(IEnumerable<string> fabricsList)
    {
        string str = string.Join(",", fabricsList);
        return str;
    }
```

For Example
str = "1,3"

Now in edit controller how can I want to select Text in ListBox based on the above string.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        fad_Data fad_Data = db.fad_Data.Find(id);
        fad_Data.sizeList = fad_Data.size.Split(',').ToList().Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Text = s, Value = s });
        if (fad_Data == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(fad_Data);
    }
```

Using above code I get the error

**An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code**
at line

fad_Data.sizeList = fad_Data.size.Split(',').ToList().Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Text = s, Value = s });

How it can be done.

Comment: please include the code where you declare `db` variable and what is the properties/methods of `fad_Data`

Comment: <pre>public class fad_Data
    {   
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Size.")]
        public string size { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> sizeList { get; set; }
    }</pre>

Comment: @MayankBhuvnesh so you are asking you do you want to show with the selected values when you click on edit?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to select back ListBox Items based on that string value.
Like in the above case str="1,3" so I want that the values in the ListBox at the position 1 and 3 should get selected.

Answer (score 0):

You are mos probably trying to assign an `IEnumerable` to a `List<T>` type which causes the `ArgumentNullException`.

The following code is a much safer version.

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            fad_Data fad_Data = db.fad_Data.Find(id);
            fad_Data?.sizeList = fad_Data?.size?.Split(',').ToList().Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Text = s, Value = s }).ToList(); // You need to add ToList() at the end.
            if (fad_Data.sizeList == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(fad_Data);
        }
```

`var bar = foo?.buz();` this conditional access can be translated into

```
if(foo != null)
{
   bar = foo.buz();
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but still same error. Also **fad_Data.size is not null**.

Comment: @MayankBhuvnesh Are you sure that *fad_Data* is not null?

Comment: Damn Sure. 
Only **fad_Data.sizeList is null.**

Comment: @MayankBhuvnesh What is the type of that sizeList? Is it a list?

Comment: IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Comment: could you take a screenshot of the values of ` fad_Data.sizeList` during runtime? you can hover your cursor the line of code when breakpoint hits.

Comment: please expand the the result set.